# Can't connect to my Ubuntu VPS via FIleZilla

Tags: ftp, vps, filezilla

I've recently just bought a brand new OVH VPS, without anything installed except Apache. When trying to connect to the VPS via FileZilla, I'm getting:

```
Status: Connecting to xxx.xxx.xxx.x:21...
Status: Connection attempt failed with "ECONNREFUSED - Connection refused by server".
Error:  Could not connect to server
```

These are the details I'm trying to connect with:

```
Hostname: xxx.xxx.xxx.x (IP of the VPS)
Username: root
Password: ******** (root Password)
Port: 21
```

Comment: FTP is not enabled on the remote host. 

Don't use FTP; use sftp.

Comment: @vidarlo How do I use stfp?